# Removing SweetAlert2 from DOM after dialog closes

Tags: javascript, dom, sweetalert, sweetalert2

```
swal({
  title: "Etsi ohjelmaa!",
  text: "Kirjoita ohjelman nimi:",
  type: "input",
  showCancelButton: true,
  closeOnConfirm: true,
  animation: "slide-from-top",
  inputPlaceholder: nimi
}
```

I tried `onClose: $("sweet-alert").removeClass()` but it doesn't work. Also I should remove class "sweet-overlay".

So how to remove Sweet-alert from DOM after dialog closes?

https://sweetalert2.github.io/

Comment: The Sweet-alert demos are removing the DOM elements and it should for you also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SweetAlert2 removes itself after closing, proof:

[image]

Make sure you're using the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Yes `swal` remove itself when close but you can do this programmatically

```
   swal({
          title: "Etsi ohjelmaa!",
          text: "Kirjoita ohjelman nimi:",
          type: "input",
          showCancelButton: true,
          closeOnConfirm: true,
          animation: "slide-from-top",
          inputPlaceholder: nimi
        ,
          onClose: function () {
            if($("sweet-alert"))
            $("sweet-alert").remove();
          }
        })
```

and not `removeClass()` as you are write above